# How to NOT trigger hover effect on table row when hovering over specific element inside it

Tags: html, css, hover, popover

I have hover effect on table row. And inside the table there is a popover menu that appears. The problem is when hovering over popover menu it's table row hover effect gets triggered (as in attached picture).
The question is how to not trigger hover effect over table row when hovering over popover?

[Image of the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoJZN.jpg)

I attached also the markup below.

```
<table class="table__table">
<tbody>
    <tr class="table__body__tr">
        <td class="table__body__td">Comment</td>
        <td class="table__body__td">
            <button type="button" class="three-dots"></button>
            <div class="popover__menu is-opened">
                <a href="#" class="popover__link">Reply to comment</a>
                <a href="#" class="popover__link">Delete comment</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    &__body {
        &__tr {
            transition: background-color .1s;

            &:hover {
                background-color: $grey--light;
            }
        }
    }
}

.popover {
    &__menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: -1;

        width: auto;

        background-color: white;

        &.is-opened {
            z-index: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you supply more detailed explanation ? For example your css ?

Comment: @ganga Sure thing, I updated post with relevant css

Comment: Easy solution whould be add extra class to td with comment and td with button. Then you can do simple logic. Like If a is hover do something else do nothing. If you like this solution i can post js for that.

Comment: That is also an good idea. It's js dependant as in codenathan's solution so I'm gonna go with javascript to fix the behavior. And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple quick methods i can think of is

add an id to your row as such `<tr data-row_id='1'>` and then do the same over on your popup element `<div data-row_id='1'>` and then apply a function on your on hover the popup to simply add a class to tr with the same data row id to hide the tr hover effect.

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Or write another jquery function to simply find the parent row and again apply a class on hover of the popup. You can use closest() method for that

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

If you post your jquery code or if you are using plain javascript just post it here to help you further

Comment: thanks! I was hoping to avoid javascript, but it looks like that will be the only way to achieve this.